# Aligning 4 Plane Lasers to a single point for Radiation Isocenter

Tags: optics, radiation

I am interested in aligning 4 lasers. The lasers are positioned in a square room two across from each other and two on the ceiling pointing down. Each laser projects a y and x planar beam. I would like to align all 4 lasers such that the planes converge to a single "point" radiation isocenter. Is there an optical mirror setup that would be able to align them all simultaneously? Or any other method?

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Each laser projects a y and x planar beam. "

Comment: https://dwqqsnxxyt153.cloudfront.net/fileadmin/user_upload/en/industries/radiation_therapy/apollo_bro_en_2-3_2019-05-16.pdf

Comment: this is a link to the type being used...rather than trying to explain it in words

Comment: You can have stages with multiple degrees of freedom. Often there is a finely threaded micrometer to turn and a spring to prevent backlash ( a kinematic stage). Then you have fine control over the pointing of the laser. Same with mirrors. In your case you might want to be able to rotate in addition to just moving XYZ. But the companies Newport,  Thor labs sell these types of components.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you want.  The illustration appears to show a green laser being scanned in two directions producing a cross on the bed of the instrument.  How does that happen if the laser is on the wall at the height of the bed?  Reflected from the large ... thing?  I'm guessing that you are doing something different.  Whatever it is, you want four crosses to intersect at the same point in space.  @UVphoton is correct, but there's also the [Risley prism pair](https://www.edmundoptics.com/f/Risley-Prism-Mount/15008/), one element that steers a beam.